# UNION ALL with WHERE doesn't SUM, echoes two numbers

Tags: mysql, group-by, union, where-clause, union-all

I solved my problems with UNION ALL by myself nearly completely. Only I have a problem with this code:

```
"SELECT ID, SUM(Goals) AS G FROM
(SELECT  ID, Goals FROM Table1 WHERE ID='8' OR ID='2' UNION ALL 
SELECT ID, Goals FROM Table2 WHERE ID='8' OR ID='2') AS derivedTable
GROUP BY ID"

echo $daten['G']
```

This code is supposed to give me the Goals from ID 8 + ID 2 together in a Sum. Unfortunately it gives me the SUM of Goals from Table 1+2 ID=8 (e.g. 20) and the SUM of Goals from Table 1+2 ID=2 (e.g. 40) like this:

2040

I would like this code to reply 60 instead, so the SUM of Table 1+2 of ID 2+8. I tried to add a SUM() to all UNION statements, but it didn't work. I tried to put the "Where ID" part after the bracket, but it didn't work.

Is there another possibility? Or do I have to change the code completely?

Comment: So, why do you GROUP BY ID then?

Comment: Remove `Group by id` at the very end.

Comment: ... I thought the Group By is necessary for combining the numbers .... :D I'm very happy that it worked now! thanks, both of you.... so simple but i would have NEVER deleted the Group by statement. I tried to change from Group By ID to Group by Goal and nothing was shown afterwards, so I was sure it was important.